# Find the next number in a sequence

Tags: numbers

This has been a programming problem which has interested me for a while.

You give the program a squence of numbers seperated by commas. It then finds a suitable formula from these numbers to find the next number in the sequence.

```
In: 1,2,3,4,5
Out: 6

In: 2,4,6,8
Out: 10

In: 10,8,6,4
Out: 2
```

I'm not sure if this problem is much more complex than it appears, in which case it may not be suitable for code golf. I'm just suggesting it.

Comment: Assuming you can build infinitely complex functions to generate a sequence of numbers, the problem you're proposing is infinitely complex, that is unsolvable...

Comment: @greg0ire: It can be, but can't you just find one suitable formula to find one number? If you wanted the formula to work all the way off to infinity that might be tricky.

Comment: Suppose an algorithm does exist, that is, being able to find a formula on an arbitrary sequence of N numbers, it must be able to find a formula on the same sequence with additional one random number. Hence any program that adds a random number to the original sequence is the answer to your question.

Comment: @greg0ire - actually, assuming the size of the input is finite, this is _always_ solvable - you can fit an `n-1` degree polynomial on any given `n` points... Of course, this will be the next number in _a_ sequence, not necessarily the one the sequence author intended.

Comment: You have to limit the kind of sequences that the program should be able to handle. Sequences like 1,2,4,7,11,16 or 1,2,4,5,7,8,10 could be handled, but should it be able to make sense of a sequence like 1,2,-1,8,-19?

Comment: I predict entries to this code golf will just look up the sequences in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/).

Comment: The question is meaningless. The next number of the sequence is not well defined. Eg: 3,4,5: next number = 7, the next number in a calculator which looks like a letter when looked at upside down. Perhaps you prefer 6? And we can always find some 'reasoning' to fit any arbitrary number as the next one (for eg using polynomial interpolation)!

Comment: @Ben Shelock: After more reflexion, I think that using this function : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function you can programmatically build a function satisfying all of the constraint corresponding to any sequence. And from this function a sequence. So to sum up, I think the problem is solvable for any sequence (yes, I told the contrary just before that).

Comment: @tzaman: +1 did not see you're solution, I thought about it, but I don't remember how you can find such a polynom... mathematics are far...

Comment: @Codism: yes but if this is a code golf, no random addition will be done. The code golf is one more constraint to the problem

Comment: @greg0ire: so does code golf give any hint on what is the "next" number for the following sequence: 1 1 1 1 1 .. 1 (10000 ones)? Just in case you think the next should be one, I am using this formula: sign(10000-i)

Answer (score 4):

(Copied from my comment above): actually, assuming the size of the input is finite, this is always solvable - you can fit an `n-1` degree polynomial on any given `n` point sequence...

Trivially, in MATLAB (don't have an install with me, but it should work):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8]
poly = polyfit(x, y, 3)
nextnum = polyval(poly, 5)
```

This creates a four-point polynomial with `y` as the input sequence, fits a 3rd degree polynomial to it and evaluates it at the next point (5). Of course, there are an infinite number of functions that will generate any given `n` points, so guessing the "right" next number is impossible. However, this *will* give you a function that produces your first `n` input numbers and then a next number. Not the point, perhaps, but it's all that can be done here.

Answer (score 2):

As some others already said: Assuming finite input, there will always be at least one polynomial fitting those points (or, for that matter, a sequence), so the following PowerShell script will always generate a valid next number for at least one of the sequences:

```
1
```

It's also just one byte long, so I guess it's golfy enough.

Comment: :) If you want to be pedantic, the original requirements _do_ mention finding "a suitable _formula_ (...) to find the next number in the sequence" ;)

Comment: if you want to be pedantic, 1 is also a formula...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming problem. There are infinitely many suitable formulas, and finding a formula is not a particularly interesting problem. Finding a formula *of a certain type* may be an interesting or useful problem, depending on the type.

For example, given *n* values, there is always exactly one suitable formula that is a [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) of degree *n*. This is often useful to prove other mathematical theorems, but doesn't have many practical applications.

A keyword for this kind of problem is [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). The three examples you've given are linear interpolations; finding out whether a linear interpolation is possible and what its result would be is a relatively easy golf problem.

[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html) is a website that gathers specific sequences that people have found interesting.

Comment: Have to mention, OEIS is a brilliant resource for any project euler fans. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica

```
f = FindSequenceFunction[{#}, Length[{#}] + 1] &

>f[1,2,3,4,5]
6

>f[2,4,6,8]
10

>f[10, 8, 6, 4]
2

>f[1!, 2!, 3!, 4!, 5!]
720

>f[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
36

>f[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13] // Fibonacci numbers
21

>f[1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7] // Harmonics
1/8

>f[1, 1 + x, 1 + x + x^2, 1 + x + x^2 + x^3, 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4] // Polynomial sequences
(-1 + x^6)/(-1 + x)

>f[1, -1/2, 1/3, -1/4, 1/5, -1/6, 1/7] // Alternating signs
-1/8

>f[1^1, 2^2, 3^3, 4^4] // n^n sequence
3125

>f[Sin[Pi/4], 2 Sin[Pi/4], 3 Sin[Pi/4], 4 Sin[Pi/4]] // Trig series
5/Sqrt[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

### J, 13 characters

```
(>:@$p.~p.@<)
```

Explanation:

```
>:@$  NB. One more than the size of the input list...
p.~   NB. ... substituted into the polynomial with coefficients...
p.@<  NB. ... the coefficients of the polynomial with roots specified by the input list
```

Usage:

```
   (>:@$p.~p.@<)  1 2 3
6

   (>:@$p.~p.@<)  10 8 6 4 
_15
```

Comment: cool!! you've inspired me to learn J!


I do like "1 2 3 6" :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem illistrates how much better the brain is at pattern matching than is a computer program.  This kind of this won't be easy at all to code.  You have to program in an (in)finite amount of possible patterns and code to check them against input, hoping for a match - or multiple matches.  That isn't a golf type problem.